# Clipping a Three.js Sprite to fit it's parent Object's bounds

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a Sprite, created as follows, and added as a child of an Object with a transparent material:

```
let mySprite = new THREE.Sprite(new SpriteMaterial({
    map: myTexture
}));

mySprite.scale.set(2, 2, 1.0);
mySprite.position.set(0, 0, 0);
myObject.add(mySprite);
```

The Object has `depthWrite: false` so that I can see the Sprite through it, however, since the Object is a sphere and the Sprite is square, the corners of the Sprite overflow the Object.

Is there a way that I can clip the corners of the Sprite so that only what is within the bounds of the spherical Object shows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to make the parents draw a unique ID to the stencil buffer

```
const parentMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  ...
  stencilWrite: true,                    // turn on stenci writing
  stencilRef: stencilId,                 // write this value
  stencilZPass: THREE.ReplaceStencilOp,  // write if the depth buffer test passes
});
```

And set the sprite to only draw where that id appears in the stencil buffer

```
const spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({
  stencilWrite: true,                   // turn on writing
  stencilRef: stencilId,                // 
  stencilFunc: THREE.EqualStencilFunc,  // draw only if stencil = stencilRef;
  depthTest: false,
});
```

Note: writing to the stencil has 3 case. What to do if the stencil test fails, what to do if the depth test fails, what to do if both pass. The default for all 3 is to do nothing. So even though we are turning on `stencilWrite` true for the sprite because the 3 defaults are do nothing (THREE.KeepStencilOp) nothing will get written when the sprites are drawn.

You need to make sure the parents are drawn before the children. If they have the same position then I think that is already true. If they have different positions then you might need to set [`renderOrder`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.renderOrder). In the example above the sprites are transparent the bodies are opaque and transparent things get drawn after opaque by default.

Note, this will only work for 255 sprites since the stencil generally only has 256 possible values. Past that you'd need to render things in groups of 255 objects, clearing the stencil buffer between groups.

```js
function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

  const fov = 75;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 50;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.set(0, 2, 5);

  const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, canvas);
  controls.target.set(0, 2, 0);
  controls.update();

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color('white');

  function addLight(position) {
    const color = 0xFFFFFF;
    const intensity = 1;
    const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(color, intensity);
    light.position.set(...position);
    scene.add(light);
    scene.add(light.target);
  }
  addLight([-3, 1, 1]);
  addLight([ 2, 1, .5]);

  const bodyRadiusTop = .4;
  const bodyRadiusBottom = .2;
  const bodyHeight = 2;
  const bodyRadialSegments = 6;
  const bodyGeometry = new THREE.CylinderBufferGeometry(
      bodyRadiusTop, bodyRadiusBottom, bodyHeight, bodyRadialSegments);

  const headRadius = bodyRadiusTop * 0.8;
  const headLonSegments = 12;
  const headLatSegments = 5;
  const headGeometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(
      headRadius, headLonSegments, headLatSegments);

  function makeLabelCanvas(baseWidth, size, name) {
    const borderSize = 2;
    const ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
    const font =  `${size}px bold sans-serif`;
    ctx.font = font;
    // measure how long the name will be
    const textWidth = ctx.measureText(name).width;

    const doubleBorderSize = borderSize * 2;
    const width = baseWidth + doubleBorderSize;
    const height = size + doubleBorderSize;
    ctx.canvas.width = width;
    ctx.canvas.height = height;

    // need to set font again after resizing canvas
    ctx.font = font;
    ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';

    // scale to fit but don't stretch
    const scaleFactor = Math.min(1, baseWidth / textWidth);
    ctx.translate(width / 2, height / 2);
    ctx.scale(scaleFactor, 1);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.fillText(name, 0, 0);

    return ctx.canvas;
  }

  function makePerson(stencilId, x, labelWidth, size, name, color) {
    const canvas = makeLabelCanvas(labelWidth, size, name);
    const texture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(canvas);
    // because our canvas is likely not a power of 2
    // in both dimensions set the filtering appropriately.
    texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
    texture.wrapS = THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping;
    texture.wrapT = THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping;

    const labelMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({
      map: texture,
      transparent: true,
      stencilWrite: true,
      stencilRef: stencilId,
      stencilFunc: THREE.EqualStencilFunc,
      depthTest: false,
    });
    const bodyMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      color,
      flatShading: true,
      stencilWrite: true,
      stencilRef: stencilId,
      stencilZPass: THREE.ReplaceStencilOp,
    });

    const root = new THREE.Object3D();
    root.position.x = x;

    const body = new THREE.Mesh(bodyGeometry, bodyMaterial);
    root.add(body);
    body.position.y = bodyHeight / 2;

    const head = new THREE.Mesh(headGeometry, bodyMaterial);
    root.add(head);
    head.position.y = bodyHeight + headRadius * 1.1;

    const label = new THREE.Sprite(labelMaterial);
    root.add(label);
    label.position.y = bodyHeight * 4 / 5;

    // if units are meters then 0.01 here makes size
    // of the label into centimeters.
    const labelBaseScale = 0.01;
    label.scale.x = canvas.width  * labelBaseScale;
    label.scale.y = canvas.height * labelBaseScale;

    scene.add(root);
    return root;
  }

  makePerson(1, -3, 128, 128, '', 'purple');
  makePerson(2, -0, 128, 128, '', 'green');
  makePerson(3, +3, 128, 128, '', 'red');

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  function render() {
    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

main();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#c {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r115/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src= "https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r115/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```